# Add WinUI control to UWP Application

Tags: uwp-xaml, winui

I am trying to use new WinUI toolkit TreeView/TeachingTip/... control to my UWP Application.
I have added the references Microsoft.UI.Xaml from Nudget packages.

```
<Page 
    x:Class="UWPInVS2019.Login"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPInVS2019"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:WinCon="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
>
<Grid>
<Button />
<WinCon:TeachingTip/>
</Grid>
```

I am getting the below error message
[image]

Comment: Does the following works?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you miss adding `XamlControlsResources` to the UWP project App.xaml file. Please add the following xaml code into App.xaml file.

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For more detail, please refer [WinUI official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started) tutorial.

Comment: I have added the XamlControlsResources to App.Xaml .Its works Fine now.

Comment: If I add the XamlControlResources  in app.xaml the default styles of controls(Button  ) of UWP application get updated to WinUI controls styles(i.e rounded corner).
Without adding the XamlControlResources to App.Xaml Is there any way to add extra controls(teaching tip/treeView) of WinUI to UWP application.   My aim is to use the UWP controls and use the extra controls that where used in WinUI.

Comment: TreeView available in 1809, if we edit the min target version to 1809, you could use TreeView directly.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62963136/1232087) if you have some time for a suggestion/comment.